# Programmatically find out if fasttab is minimized on page

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

We have several fastTabs on a Dynamics NAV 2017 page. On these fastTabs are fields that are calculated using complicated functions which have a big performance impact on our page. We program in "old" C/AL code, NOT in new AL on Visual Studio Code.

Is it possible to programmatically find out if a given fastTab is minimized, so we can only calculate the fields if the fastTab is not minimized?

Comment: You can make a simple .Net Client Addin that you add to the FastTab. Then that addin can get it's parent through some .Net wizardry and eventually you'll end up at the FastTab. I'm adding it as a comment instead of an answer because: a) I've never done it b) I can't find where I've read it c) doesn't work in the Web Client and d) it's a very bad idea going forward into later versions.

Comment: The 'NAV' way would be to offload these to a 'Statistics' page so the user only sees them if they actively go looking.  I wouldn't add them to a factbox if there are performance implications unless the user looks at those values EVERY time they load that page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it’s not possible neither in c/al nor in al.

To solve your problem I would consider something like:

- create refresh/recalculate action (button) and make users click on it to see values.
- try create visual add-in, it will be called only if visible (not hidden though).
- use factboxes, because user can show/hide them using hot key (Alt+F2). Hidden factbox will not call recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

not it's not possible. What you can do is to move those fields to a FactBox because you can check that the FactBox is Visible or not...